# ¿cómo puedo convertir tipo dato number a cadena?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Al momento de imprimir me sale el error de conversión o de restriccion, he intentado con to_char en la variable v_Sal pero igual me sigue saliendo error.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
 v_Sal  NUMBER(12,2);
 v_name  VARCHAR2(50);
 v_Fecha  DATE;
BEGIN
 v_Sal := ROUND(2585.6452, 2);
 v_name := INITCAP('base de datos 2');
 v_Fecha := TO_DATE('06/05/2005', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' Curso: ' || v_name || ' Fecha: ' ||     TO_CHAR(v_Fecha,'DD DAY MONTH YYYY'));
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' Salario:'  || v_Sal);
END;
```

Comment: `to_char` es la forma correcta de hacerlo.  Muéstranos tu intento y el mensaje de error que recibistes.

Comment: *Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).

Comment: y en action me sale esto:  *Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias probar con esta otra forma

`select to_binary_double(numcol) binary_double,
to_binary_float(numcol)  binary_float_number,
to_number(numcol)        number_datatype
from mytab;`

este es link donde encontre la info [Aqui puedes ver el ejemplo](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_convert_number_to_floating_point.htm)